# カスタムキーボードエクステンションでRealmを使いたいが実行時にフレームワークが見つからないエラー

Tags: swift, ios8, realm

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
  Referenced from: /Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/830BF1AF-9059-445F-AC17-FC40D97C9C6E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9D7F484F-0512-49EE-92B4-9F00FCB00351/test.app/PlugIns/test-key.appex/test-key
  Reason: image not found
```

上記のエラーが出ます。

改善方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ビルドする際に。フレームワークをエクステンションのバンドルにコピーする必要があります。
そのために、ターゲットのBuild Phasesの設定にフレームワークをバンドル内の所定の位置にコピーする設定を追加します。

Xcodeでプロジェクトを選択して、カスタムキーボードエクステンションのターゲットを選択します。

そして、「Build Phases」を選択し、左上の「＋」ボタンから「New Copy Files Phase」を追加します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一番下に「Copy Files」というフェーズが追加されるので、そこにフレームワークをコピーする設定を追加します。

コピー先は「Frameworks」でなければならないので、「Destinaton」を「Frameworks」に変更します。

そして、「＋」ボタンを押して「Realm.framework」と「RealmSwift.framework」を追加します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここまで設定が済めば、再ビルドして実行してみてください。
エラーが解消されるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございました。解決です。が、データが読めません。別途質問しました。よろしくお願いいたします。